# What causes a Session value to change from the one inserted?

Tags: php, session, url

I have the following classes
A Session class

```
<?php
class Session
{
    public static function exists($name)
    {
        return (isset($_SESSION[$name])) ? true : false;
    }

    public static function delete($name)
    {
        if (self::exists($name))
        {
            unset($_SESSION[$name]);
        }
    }

    public static function get($name)
    {
        return $_SESSION[$name];
    }

    public static function put($name, $value)
    {
        return $_SESSION[$name] = $value;
    }
}
```

A Token class

```
<?php
class Token
{
    public static function generate()
    {
        return Session::put('token', md5(uniqid()));
    }

    public static function check($token)
    {
        //var_dump(Session::get('token'));
        //var_dump($token);
        //die();

        if(Session::exists('token') && $token === Session::get('token'))
        {
            Session::delete('token');
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

An Input class

```
<?php
class Input
{
    public static function exists($type = 'post')
    {
        switch ($type)
        {
            case 'post':
                return (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;
                break;
            case 'get':
                return (!empty($_GET)) ? true : false;
                break;  

            case 'uri':
                //echo 'Well we are here. <br>'; 
                return (!empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) ? true : false;
                break;
            case 'session':
                return (!empty($_SESSION)) ? true : false;  
            default:
                return false;
                break;
        }
    }

    public function get($item, $method = 'post')
    {
        switch ($method) {
            case 'post':
                if(isset($_POST[$item])) return $_POST[$item];
                break;
            case 'get':
                if(isset($_GET[$item])) return $_GET[$item];
                break;
            case 'session':
                if(isset($_SESSION[$item])) return $_SESSION[$item];
                break;  
            case 'server':
                if(isset($_SERVER[$item])) return $_SERVER[$item];
                break;
            default:
                return "";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a signup form

```
<div class="glob-main-contents-wrapper">
    <span class="signup-header">
        <h1>Sign up</h1>
        <a href="http://localhost/mysite/signin">Already a member?</a>
    </span>
    <form action="http://localhost/mysite/scripts/signup" id="signup-form" class="signup-form" method="post">
        <div class="field">
            <input type="text" class="username" id="username" name="username" placeholder=" Username" value="<?php echo Input::get('username', 'session') ?>">

            <span class="field-error" id="username-error">

            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <input type="text" class="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php echo Input::get('email', 'session') ?>">

            <span class="field-error" id="email-error">

            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <input type="password" class="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">

            <span class="field-error" id="password-error">

            </span>
        </div>

         <div class="field">
            <input type="text" class="name" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Full Name" value="<?php echo Input::get('name', 'session') ?>">

            <span class="field-error" id="name-error">

            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <input type="text" class="bio" id="bio" name="bio" placeholder="Biography" value="<?php echo Input::get('bio', 'session') ?>"">

            <span class="field-error" id="bio-error">

            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <select class="timezone" id="timezone" name="timezone" placeholder="TimeZone" style="width: 300px">
                <?php
                    $date = new Date_Time;
                    $timezones = $date->timezones();
                    foreach ($timezones as $key => $timezone)
                    {
                ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $timezone; ?>" <?php if($timezone === 'UTC') echo 'selected="selected"' ?>><?php echo $timezone; ?></option>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </select>

            <span class="field-error" id="timezone-error">

            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <input type="text" class="site" id="site" name="site" placeholder="Website" value="<?php echo Input::get('site', 'session') ?>">

            <span class="field-error" id="website-error">

            </span>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <button type="submit" class="reg-btn" id="reg-btn">Sign up</button>

            <span class="field-error" id="form-error">

                </span>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" id="token" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
    </form>
</div>
```

Then lastly i have the following script for the action in the form

```
if(Input::exists()):
    Session::put('username', Input::get('username'));
    Session::put('email', Input::get('email'));
    Session::put('name', Input::get('name'));
    Session::put('bio', Input::get('bio'));
    Session::put('site', Input::get('site'));

    if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))):
        $errors = array();
        if(empty($_POST['username'])):
            $errors[] = 'username=is required';
        else:
            //other username checks
        endif;
        //checks for other form inputs

        if(empty($errors)):
            try{ //insert into database } 
            catch(Exception $e){header('http://localhost/mysite/signup'. '/errors=?error=something went wrong');}
        else:
            $result = '';
            foreach ($errors as $key => $error)
            {
                $result .= '&'. $error;
            }
            Router::to('http://localhost/mysite/signup'. '/errors=?' .$result);
        endif;
    else:
        Router::to('http://localhost/mysite/signup'. '/errors=?invalid token');
    endif;
endif;
```

When i go to the address http://localhost/mysite/signup and i input all the form data correctly i.e pass all the error checks in the script, i manage to signup without a problem. However, when i make a mistake i.e fail on at least one error check i end up with a url like this http://localhost/mysite/signin/errors=?&username=is20%required which is what i want so that i can use the get variables to highlight errors. When i then try to signup i get an invalid token url. This happens whether i have errors or not. After uncommenting the vardumps in the Token class i find that the value in the $_SESSION['token'] is not equal to the value that was generated. What could be causing my $_SESSION['token'] to be different than the the one generated?

Comment: I see nothing in all that code about `$_SESSION['token']`. Sounds like you are not maintaining a session. *"session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed..."*

Comment: When i generate the token in the hidden value of the form, that is where $_SESSION['token'] is is set. The session_start is at the top of the file where the form is found

Comment: `return $_SESSION[$name] = $value;` this looks wrong

Comment: So you are updating the value of `$_SESSION['token']` when not desired? It's not empty... it's set to something unexpected. Stands to reason you are setting it when not intending to. Hard to help not seeing the relevant code.

Comment: No, i am generating it in the hidden input where i want to output it i.e where i want to use it. On generating it i am inserting it into $_SESSION['token'] so that when the user sends data for registration i can compare the two